# Javascript RegExp with extended latin

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to get from following text: *Straße!=Test*

the following results:

```
1: Straße
2: !=
3: Test
```

mit current solution is

```
/([\w\sß]+)([=!<>]{1,2})(.*)/
```

But it will break when i use more characters like äüö ...

What is the best solution to match the first word and the middle operators:

```
=
!=
>
>=
<
<=
```

Comment: Try `/(.*?)(!?=|[><]=?)(.*)/` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkRlXT/1)).

Comment: Then you may also try `s.split(/(!?=|[><]=?)/)`

Answer (score 0):

You limited first match of regex by `([\w\sß]+)`. Use `(.*?)` to matching any character. So your regex changed to `/(.*?)([!<>]{1,2})(.*)/` that match any character before and after operators.

```js
var str = "ä-Straße!=Test-ü";
var match = str.match(/(.*?)([=!<>]{1,2})(.*)/).slice(1);
console.log(match);
```